# Tensorflow's TimeDistributed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In Tensorflow's TimeDistributed [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TimeDistributed). There is an example:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10, 128, 128, 3))
conv_2d_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(conv_2d_layer)(inputs)
outputs.shape
```

And the output is `TensorShape([None, 10, 126, 126, 64])`. How come it ends up with this shape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a batch of `32` video samples, where each sample is a `128x128` RGB image, across `10` timesteps. The batch input shape is `(32, 10, 128, 128, 3)`.

You can then use `TimeDistributed` to apply the same `Conv2D` layer to each of the 10 `timesteps`, independently as shown below

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10, 128, 128, 3))
conv_2d_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(conv_2d_layer)(inputs)
outputs.shape
```

Output:

```
TensorShape([None, 10, 126, 126, 64])
```

> And the output is TensorShape([None, 10, 126, 126, 64]). How come it
> ends up with this shape?

Here is the formula to calculate output shape of convolution layer

[image]

In this case, you have `128` input features, `3` is the convolution kernel size, `0` is convolution padding size and `1` is convolution stride size (by default if not provided) then output features is `(128+2*0-3)/1+1=126`.

Same apply for other dimension. So now you have a `126x126` image for one filter.

If you apply this for `64` times you will have another dimension `126x126x64`, now output shape across `10` time steps is `[None, 10, 126, 126, 64]`. Here `None` is batch_size. For more information you can refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TimeDistributed) and [this](https://blog.mlreview.com/a-guide-to-receptive-field-arithmetic-for-convolutional-neural-networks-e0f514068807).

Comment: Finally! I have waited for the answer for 2 weeks. Just one follow-up question, what do you mean by "applying this for 64 times"?

Comment: `64` is the number of output filters in the convolution layer i.e. `Conv2D(64, (3, 3))`.

Comment: @Ng Lok Chun, If you are satisfied with my answer, can you please upvote my answer.Thanks!